# Exit Firefox from Shell Script

Tags: command-line, scripts

I've already tried `pkill -19 firefox`, but it crashes. At the next start it asks if the last session should be opened again. Is it possible to terminate the browser without crash?

Comment: See https://superuser.com/q/583246/73961 for a more complete discussion, if Google has (also) brought you here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any use of `pkill` is going to crash it; that's essentially its purpose.  Use a program like [`wmctrl`](https://tomas.styblo.name/wmctrl/) instead, to tell it to exit properly.